# How to get total service time of all servers in Omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

```
               simtime_t serviceTime= par("serviceTime");
               TotalServiceTime=TotalServiceTime+serviceTime;
                          EV<<"service Time= "<<serviceTime<<endl;
                           EV<<"Total Service Time= "<<TotalServiceTime<<endl;
```

This is the code which I wrote to give me total service time of all servers. What it gives me is that it accumulates the service times of each server by itself in the same variable. So I don't know the total service time of all servers.
I also initialized TotalServiceTime by 0 in initialize(). 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your question is that you have multiple server modules in your simulation. A good way to get the total service time from all of them is using signals (described in the omnet++ manual in chapter 4.14).

To do this you need to emit signals containing the service time of each server. You then create a separate module within your network that listens to the signals emitted by your servers and accumulates the service time for all of them.